# XStream class cannot be resolved

Tags: java, xml, exception, xstream

I'm getting an XStream error with the following setup. I must be crazy. What's wrong?

The request class

```
@XStreamAlias("RequestTO")
public class RequestTO {

    @XStreamImplicit
    private List<SkuMerchTO> skuNumbers;
...
}
```

The nested object class

```
@XStreamAlias("skuMerch")
public class SkuMerchTO {

    @XStreamAlias("skuNumber")
    @XStreamAsAttribute
    private Integer skuNumber;

    @XStreamAlias("dept")
    @XStreamAsAttribute
    private Short department;

    @XStreamAlias("class")
    @XStreamAsAttribute
    private Short cls;

    @XStreamAlias("subClass")
    @XStreamAsAttribute
    private Short subClass;
...
}
```

XStream code to decode the XML to an object:

```
XStream stream = new XStream();
stream.processAnnotations(SkuMerchTO.class);
stream.processAnnotations(RequestTO.class);
RequestTO request =  (RequestTO)stream.fromXML(requestXml);
```

XML input string:

```
<RequestTO>
     <skuMerch skuNumber="123456" dept="1" class="2" subClass="3"/>
     <skuMerch skuNumber="234567" dept="4" class="5" subClass="6"/>  
</RequestTO>
```

Error in Stacktrace:
---- Debugging information ----
message             : 2 : 2
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : 2 : 2
class               : [...]RequestTO
required-type       : [...]SkuMerchTO
path                : /RequestTO/skuNumberList/skuMerch
line number         : 3
.-------------------------------
com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException: 2 : 2 : 2 : 2
---- Debugging information ----
message             : 2 : 2
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : 2 : 2
class               : [...]RequestTO
required-type       :[..]SkuMerchTO
path                : /RequestTO/skuNumberList/skuMerch
line number         : 3
.-------------------------------

If I create the objects and do toXML I get this:

```
<RequestTO>
  <skuMerch skuNumber="0" dept="1" class="2" subClass="2"/>
  <skuMerch skuNumber="1" dept="1" class="2" subClass="2"/>
  <skuMerch skuNumber="2" dept="1" class="2" subClass="2"/>
</RequestTO>
```

EDIT: The hilarious thing is, if do this:

```
 stream.fromXML(stream.toXML(object));
```

It still fails on the from XML part!

Comment: I don't understand the outputted XML if you have the annotation for aliasing `RequestTo` to `Request`...

Comment: my bad, that was a typo. The alias is "RequestTO"

Comment: I entered your code (almost) directly, and had no issues from or to xml using xstream 1.4.2. Which version are you using?  I did create a package for the classes, though.

Comment: using 1.3.1. It could be that they discontinued using the system attribute for "class" as default in 1.4 since that is what the issue was. See Ian Roberts' answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The attribute named `class` has a special meaning to XStream, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4923742/592139) suggests that you can tell XStream to use a different attribute for this purpose via something like

```
stream.aliasSystemAttribute("__class", "class");
```

This would cause XStream to use `__class` as the "special" attribute, and treat `class` as a normal one.  Or, if you know you don't need the XStream magic handling of `class` for any of your objects you can say

```
stream.aliasSystemAttribute(null, "class");
```

to tell it not to use this feature at all.

You may also need to use `itemFieldName="skuMerch"` on the `@XStreamImplicit` annotation, as per the [XStream annotation tutorial](http://x-stream.github.io/annotations-tutorial.html).

Comment: Yep, that was it. Didn't like "class" as an alias. I'll have you your bounty after the 24 hour period is up. Thanks!